# Comparing two lists of string containing dates

Tags: java, date, time

I have tow lists of string containing dates in a particular format given below;

Lets say;

```
List1<String>=[2016-12-03T16:18:02.000Z, 2016-12-02T16:18:02.000Z, 2016-12-01T16:18:02.000Z]
List2<String>=[2016-12-03T17:34:49.000Z, 2016-11-21T17:34:50.000Z, 2016-11-21T17:34:49.000Z, 2016-12-02T17:34:50.000Z, 2016-11-21T17:34:49.000Z, 2016-11-21T17:34:50.000]
```

I actually wanted to compare these two lists and the condition is that the dates `"2016-12-03T16:18:02.000Z"` in `List1` and  `"2016-12-03T17:34:49.000Z"` in `List2` actually falls on the same day i.e. they should be matched and increment the count. I have implemented it by changing the format of both the lists as `"yyyy-MM-dd"` but is it possible to compare these without changing the format of date?

The code i have done is:

```
static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
public static List<String> getLocalDatesFinalListAsString(List<Date> localDateListAsDate){
    System.out.println("-----Formatted Past Three Days-----");
    for (Date date : localDateListAsDate) {
        int hoursToSubtract = -5;
        int minutesToSubtract = -45;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, hoursToSubtract);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesToSubtract);
        String dateLocal = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        localDateFinalList.add(dateLocal);
    }
    System.out.println(localDateFinalList.size());
    return localDateFinalList;
}

public static List<String> getJsonDatesFinalListAsString(List<Date> jsonDatesListAsDate){
    for (Date date : jsonDatesListAsDate) {
        String dateJson=sdf.format(date);
        jsonDateFinalList.add(dateJson);
    }
    System.out.println(jsonDateFinalList.size());
    return jsonDateFinalList;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    int count=0;
    List<String> stringListOfPastThreeDates = getLocalDatesFinalListAsString(dateListOfPastThreeDates);
    List<String> stringListOfJsonDates = getJsonDatesFinalListAsString(dateListOfJsonDates);

    for (String localDate : stringListOfPastThreeDates) {
        if (stringListOfJsonDates.contains(localDate)) {
            count++;
            System.out.println("Falls on the same day");
        }
    }   
}
```

But for the list to compare, the count value increases if they only have same values in both the lists.

Comment: Use the right abstraction. You want to compare instants to each other. So don't use Strings. Use Instants. Parse all your strings to Instants, and then use the date-handling methods that Instant proposes. For example, to check that two instants fall on the same day in the UTC timezone, use `instant1.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate().equals(instant2.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate())`

Comment: When you say "falls on the same day" do you mean the date by [UTC](https://duckduckgo.com/coordinated_Universal_Time) as seen in that string, or do you mean the date of some particular time zone such as `America/Montreal` or `Pacific/Auckland`? A new day dawns earlier in the east. So for any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

Comment: Actually the list one is my local time and the second list is of UCT

Comment: @JagaranShrestha Edit your Question to include all this information, including examples of the other list if different. You still have not answered my question exactly, what time zone to use in comparing dates? A moment after midnight in Paris France is a new day while still "yesterday" in Montréal Québec. Also, fix your example data if that last item is missing its `Z`.

Comment: UCT time zone to compare Z